# How can I merge two lists of dictionaries into 1, where numeric values for identical keys get added?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have two list of dictionaries:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'a': 1, 'name1': "jane"}, {'b': 2, 'name1': 'jack'}, {'c': 3, 'name1': 'nak'},{'d': 3, 'name1': 'nak'}]
dict_to_check = [{'a': 1, 'name2': "jone"}, {'b': 2, 'name2': 'doe'}, {'d': 3, 'name2': 'nick'}]
```

I want to output , please help to give me some solutions :

```
[
      {'a': 2, 'name1': "jane", 'name2': "jone"},
      {'b': 4, 'name1': 'jack','name2': 'doe'},
      {'c': 3, 'name1': 'nak'},
      {'d': 6, 'name1': 'nak','name2': 'nick'}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create two temporary dictionaries one with the numbers and one with the names based on the letter and then merge them

```
numbers = {}
names = {}
for d in list_of_dicts + dict_to_check:
    key, name = d.keys()
    numbers[key] = numbers.get(key, 0) + d[key]
    names.setdefault(key, {}).update({name: d[name]})

lst = [{k: v, **names[k]} for k, v in numbers.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly your structure, but this may work:

```
dict1 = [
    {'a': 1, 'name1': "jane"},
    {'b': 2, 'name1': 'jack'},
    {'c': 3, 'name1': 'nak'},
    {'d': 3, 'name1': 'nak'}
]

dict2 = [
    {'a': 1, 'name2': "jone"},
    {'b': 2, 'name2': 'doe'},
    {'d': 3, 'name2': 'nick'}
]

res = []
for d1 in dict1:
    letter, name = list(d1.keys())
    for d2 in dict2:
        if letter in d2:
            res.append({
                letter: d1[letter] + d2[letter],
                'name1': d1['name1'],
                'name2': d2['name2']
            })
            break
    else:
        res.append({
            letter: d1[letter],
            'name1': d1['name1'],
        })
print(*res, sep='\n') # nice printing
```

Answer (score 1):

certainly not the most elegant solution. but could work

```
# input
dict_to_check = [{'a': 1, 'name1': "jone"}, {'b': 2, 'name1': 'doe'}, {'d': 3, 'name1': 'nick'}]
list_of_dicts = [{'a': 1, 'name2': "jane"}, {'b': 2, 'name2': 'jack'}, {'c': 3, 'name2': 'nak'}]

# concat both lists
dict_all = dict_to_check + list_of_dicts

# put all dicts into the result list and merge if dict with same first key exists
result_dicts = []
for dict_item in dict_all:
    # get first key
    keys = list(dict_item.keys())
    first_key = keys[0]
    # check if dict exists
    found_dict = next((dict_res for dict_res in result_dicts if list(dict_res.keys())[0] == first_key), None)
    if found_dict is None:
        # add new dict
        result_dicts.append(dict_item)
    else:
        # extend existing dict
        for key in keys:
            found_dict[key] = dict_item[key]
            
print("result_dicts", result_dicts)
  
# sort the dict if needed
result_dicts_sorted = sorted(result_dicts, key=lambda d: list(d.keys())[0]) 

print("result_dicts_sorted", result_dicts_sorted)
```